# Filter, subtract or group by - what is the most efficient? (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin

For example, we have a list that we want to divide into two parts with the specific predicate.

First, we can use `filter` and `filterNot`.

```
val trueList = list.filter(predicate)
val falseList = list.filterNot(predicate)
```

Second, we can use `filter` and `subtract`:

```
val trueList = list.filter(predicate)
val falseList = list.subtract(trueList)
```

Third, we can use `groupBy`:

```
val groupBy = list.groupBy(predicate)
val trueList = groupBy[true]
val falseList = groupBy[false]
```

What is the most efficient, fastest way? And can we do this with some other functions?

I think a second option with `subtract` is the worst, am I right?

Comment: You missed the most obvious choice: [partition](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/partition.html).

Comment: Thanks for the `partition`, I knew that there should be a simple option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I tried to understand which option is the fastest: `filter`, `subtract`, `groupBy` or `partition` (thank [Marko Topolnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1103872/marko-topolnik) for a hint). And I used `measureTimeMillis` to know elapsed time of each option:

```
private fun checkTime(list: List<Int>, predicate: (Int) -> Boolean) {
    var sum = 0L
    repeat(times) { sum += checkPartition(list, predicate) }
    println("partition: ${sum/times}")

    sum = 0L
    repeat(times) { sum += checkFilter(list, predicate) }
    println("filter: ${sum/times}")

    sum = 0L
    repeat(times) { sum += checkSubtract(list, predicate) }
    println("subtract: ${sum/times}")

    sum = 0L
    repeat(times) { sum += checkGroupBy(list, predicate) }
    println("group by: ${sum/times}")
}


private fun checkGroupBy(list: List<Int>, predicate: (Int) -> Boolean): Long {
    return measureTimeMillis {
        val groupBy = list.groupBy(predicate)
        val falseList = groupBy[false]
        val trueList = groupBy[true]
    }
}

private fun checkSubtract(list: List<Int>, predicate: (Int) -> Boolean): Long {
    return measureTimeMillis {
        val trueList = list.filter(predicate)
        val falseList = list.subtract(trueList)
    }
}

private fun checkFilter(list: List<Int>, predicate: (Int) -> Boolean): Long {
    return measureTimeMillis {
        val trueList = list.filter(predicate)
        val falseList = list.filterNot(predicate)
    }
}

private fun checkPartition(list: List<Int>, predicate: (Int) -> Boolean): Long {
    return measureTimeMillis {
        val pair = list.partition(predicate)
        val trueList = pair.first
        val falseList = pair.second
    }
}
```

I checked it with 10 times repetition and this predicate:

```
val predicate = { it: Int -> it % 2 == 0 }
```

And with lists with a different size:

```
var list = (1..1_000_000).toList()
checkTime(list, predicate)
```

> partition: 16
>   filter: 21
>   subtract: 81
>   group by: 18

```
list = (1..2_000_000).toList()
checkTime(list, predicate)
```

> partition: 30
>   filter: 42
>   subtract: 241
>   group by: 36

```
list = (1..3_000_000).toList()
checkTime(list, predicate)
```

> partition: 35
>   filter: 59
>   subtract: 233
>   group by: 63

So, [partition](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/partition.html) is a really good option for dividing list to a two parts.

Tell me, please, if I did something wrong.

Comment: And an FYI for partition case. You can take advantage of Kotlin's destructuring operation. So it becomes `val (trueList, falseList) = list.partition(predicate)`. IntelliJ even provides it as an intention and will make the code change for you.